# How to prove this inequality where $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are positive reals?

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c,d ∈ \Bbb R^+$ , such that $a+b+c+d+abcd = 5$. Prove the inequality:

$1/a+1/b+1/c+1/d \geqslant 4$.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Have you found a way to apply the assumption $a + b + c + d + abcd = 5$ somewhere?

Comment: I tried some things like establishing relation between $a+b+c+d$ and $1/a+1/b+1/c+1/d$ but $abcd$ troubles me. I have got a solution but hoping for a simpler one without derivatives as I'm a 10th grade student.

Answer (score 1):

By $AM-GM$ we get $$\frac{a+b+c+d+abcd}{5}\geq\sqrt[5]{(abcd)^2}$$ so $$1\geq abcd$$
$$AM-GM$$ again
$$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}\geq 4\sqrt[4]{\frac{1}{abcd}}$$
Now we get $$4\sqrt[4]\frac{1}{abcd}\geq 4$$ if $$1\geq abcd$$ and this follows from the condition.

Comment: nice +1..............

Comment: Thank you Michael, but just corrected!

Comment: Just a problem, how $4(1/abcd^1/2) >= 4$ if $1>=abcd$

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: 4th step............

Comment: This is the well-known $AM-GM$ inequality proved by Cauchy.

Comment: My problem with your solution is same as with Christian's  If abcd>=4 then 1/abcd=<4

Comment: And what want you to know?

Comment: Ok understood. Just messed everything up. THX btw

Answer (score 0):

Since $$a+b+c+d \geq 4\sqrt[4]{abcd}$$ we have $$t^4+4t-5\leq 0$$ where $t=\sqrt[4]{abcd}>0$. Becasue of $$(t-1)(t^3+t^2+t+5)\le 0$$ we have $t\leq 1$

Finaly we have: $$1/a+1/b+1/c+1/d \geq 4\sqrt[4]{1/t}\geq 4$$

Comment: Thx............